# How to implement the DATE PICKER in PhoneGap? is there any alternative other than mobscroll. If I use Jquery I' m getting below error

Tags: datepicker, phonegap, mobiscroll

How to implement the DATE PICKER in PhoneGap/Android? Some people are suggesting  to use [Mobicroll](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime), I guess it is paid. So anyone please explain me in detail how to use a 3rd party tool/plugin for the datpicker usage in HTML

Answer (score 0):

I guess Mobiscroll is paid one that too for huge amount. For 2 or 3 functionalities we cant ot go for Mobiscroll.

You can go for jQuery UI which have some options and you can go for [Bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) also.

Include the jQuery CDN in your HTML file.

Here you need to carefully to do 2 things. Are you using the bootstrap or not?

If not, no problem. You can use Jquery UI datepicker.

**If yes**, you have to first include the Bootstrap CDN and after that you have to include jQuery CDN.

Copy the items like below. Otherwise you will get Uncaught TypeError:

> $(...).datepicker is not a function.

(If you copy jQuery Items and after that if you copy Bootstrap)

```
<!-- Adding below 3 files for Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--Adding below files for jQuery UI-->
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```